# How can the readings from ANOVA one way test help with finding correlation?

Tags: correlation, anova, categorical-data

I've just started on data analytics. Currently I am using python to find the correlation between categorical data (independent) and continuous data (dependent). I know that the test is used to determine if there are statistically significant differences between the means of three or more independent (unrelated) groups. However, how does knowing the differences between the means help with finding the correlation?

Comment: Define your correlation first, then try to get it. Suppose one variable is race (White, African American, Other) and another is weight of person. What is the correlation?

Comment: Your ANOVA implies a predicted or fitted value for the dependent variable. You can look at the correlation between that and the observed value.